# Installing Kubuntu and disk partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, kubuntu

I decided to use linux lately.
I recently burnt the kubuntu 20.4 image in a 16gb flash drive. I tried installing it on my own. I had difficulties, though I was able to install the system.
I went through the installation process easily but the problem was in the disk space settings. I don't want to do dual boot, I want to have a clean linux with my whole disk capacity.
I am running Kubuntu now. As I said everything is okay except for the disk space set-up because I can see most of my disk space unusable now. I would like to store movies and other documents, so I need that space, but how?
Can anyone please inform me about the disk partitions and how that works in Linux and why am I not able to use rest of my space.

here is how it looks like when I enter the command Sudo parted --list:

```
Model: ATA TS120GSSD220S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  24.0GB  24.0GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      24.0GB  120GB   96.0GB  extended
 5      24.0GB  28.0GB  3999MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 6      28.0GB  120GB   92.0GB  logical   ext4


Model: ATA WDC WD5000LPCX-2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  1855MB  1854MB  ntfs         primary
```

I think Linux is a great os and a combined human effort.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a very old BIOS system? You show MBR partitioning on sda, but gpt on sdb. UEFI installs use gpt partitioning.  If not using Windows best not to keep NTFS partitions. Back up any data you want to keep, erase partition and create new ext4 partition. NTFS requires chkdsk & defrag which cannot be done from Linux. If you left Windows hibernation on the NTFS partitions is locked from Linux to prevent damage. You can force mount  as read only to backup, if required.Or use Windows repair tools to turn hibernation off.

Comment: Your boot drive looks quite ordrinary to me. I suspect you might be referring to your 500GB non-boot drive (the Question is not clear). Use the "Disks" utility to re-partition and reformat your non-boot 500GB drive (WARNING: That action will destroy all existing data on the non-boot drive). Then you will have plenty of space.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. I was just asking the wrong question. I wanted to mount my partitioned disk space so that I can use it.